# Android: TextInputLayout always leaves some space from top

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialogCentralContent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneNumberInfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_white_rounded">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="@={dataContext.phonePrefix}"
        style="@style/Widget.App.PurchaseAmountEditText" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        tools:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorText="@{dataContext.validator.phoneValidation}">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="@={dataContext.phoneNumber}"
            style="@style/Widget.App.PurchaseAmountEditText" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the second `EditText` is rendered lower than the first one. When I look at it in the visual editor of Android Studio I can see that the `TextInputLayout` has some free space at its top, however setting `paddingTop="0dp"` didn't change anything. So how to make those two `EditText`s render the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` will leave room at the top for the floating hint text. If you're not using the floating hint, you can remove that space by adding the following to the opening `<TextInputLayout>` element.

```
app:hintEnabled="false"
```

The regular hint text will still be visible on the `TextInputEditText` when it's empty.

---

<sup>N.B. – This answer does not apply to the current Material Components version, which is markedly different than the original.</sup>