# Removing TextInputLayout extra top padding

Tags: android, padding, android-textinputlayout

TextInputLayout seems to always have some extra padding at the top (no matter that all margins/paddings are set to 0):

[image]

The layout looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/txt_amount"
            style="@style/EditTextStyle"
            android:hint="@string/hint_amount"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

How to remove this extra space?

Comment: Do you mean above the text, or above the `View` bounds? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40696708

Comment: @MikeM. I mean above the view (space between `EditText` and top border of the `TextInputLayout`).

Comment: Yeah, that's for the floating hint. If you're not going to use that, you can disable it with `hintEnabled="false"` in the layout XML, like is shown in my linked answer. Oh, I guess someone posted it here, too.

Comment: How to remove mysterious padding on the sides though?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can remove extra space above AppCompatEditText by setting `app:hintEnabled="false"` to TextInputLayout but it won't display hint until you re-enable that.

For more info goto [Android Developer site -TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)

Checkout below code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_amount"
        style="@style/EditTextStyle"
        android:hint="@string/hint_amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Hope this helpfull..

@Rajesh

Comment: Ok, this looks reasonable. Will accept unless there is some better solution.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer didn't work for me on version - `1.2.1` so I did some experiments and realized that the padding doesn't actually come from the `TextInputLayout`, rather it's from `TextInputEditText`. So first I removed the padding from that, but it looked uneven, so I set custom padding to `TextInputEditText` and it worked fine. Just add this line `android:padding="16dp"` to the `TextInputEditText` replacing 16dp with your desired value.

Answer (score 15):

having a structure like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/til_project"
                    style="@style/LoginTextInputLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:errorEnabled="false">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/totalPiecesProduct"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

the keys are:

`app:errorEnabled="false"` in `TextInputLayout`

```
`android:padding="0dp"` in `TextInputEditText`
```

before:

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: how to remove the margin around the Edittext?

Answer (score 2):

to remove all paddings in your TextInputLayout, you can set `app:boxCollapsedPaddingTop` to 0dp in TextInputLayout and `android:padding` to 0dp in Edittext.

Comment: android:padding to 0dp in Edittext worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by overriding the default padding style of TextInputStyle, (Material version should be above 1.1.0)

```
 <style name="CustomInputLayoutPadding" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/CustomOverlayFilledPadding</item>
</style>
```

then

```
 <style name="CustomeOverlayFilledPadding">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/CustomTextInputEditPaddingStyle</item>
</style>
```

then

```
   <style name="CustomTextInputEditPaddingStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">
    <item name="android:paddingStart" ns2:ignore="NewApi">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd" ns2:ignore="NewApi">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had done using set manual padding in TextInputEditText

```
android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_12sdp"
android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

As of `compileSdk 33` or Material library version v1.8.0, I added the attribute

```
app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
```

in `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Add `hintEnabled = false` to TextInputLayout in the layout XML.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white">

            <com.bugle.customviews.RobotoLightEditText

                android:id="@+id/edtName"
                style="@style/StyledTilEditText"
                android:hint="@string/name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="textCapWords" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score -4):

Add this line in EditText

**android:translationY="-10dp"**

Comment: This looks like a hack. Would try to avoid it if it is possible to set this to zero somewhere.